# How to get value of a textarea after document.ready(function(){ }) in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, textarea, casperjs

I want to ask that how can I get value of text box after assigning it using this method?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#job_description').val('This is test');
});
```

When value is assigned to text then it is not longer to access using Casperjs method

```
console.log(this.fetchText('#job_description'));
```

But if I enter value using this method

```
<textarea name="" id="job_description"> This is test </textarea>
```

then this is accessible using this method

```
console.log(this.fetchText('#job_description'));
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `fetchText` retrieves the text child of the element. But when you use

```
$('#job_description').val('This is test');
```

to set the textarea value, you actually set a property of the textarea. This does not update the `innerHTML`/`children` of the textarea in any way. You need to retrieve the value like this:

```
var text = casper.evaluate(function(){
    return document.querySelector('#job_description').value;
});
```

or this

```
var text = casper.evaluate(function(){
    return $('#job_description').val();
});
```